# Hide year text in asp calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot find anything to remove the year text from an asp calendar. Is there a way to do it without custom rendering?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the TitleFormat attribute?

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" TitleFormat="Month"></asp:Calendar>
```